# Jquery find closest ID and Select Value?

Tags: jquery, select

I have a table made up of rows like this:

```
<tr class='child1'>
    <td colspan="2"><img class="parent" src="show.gif">
        <select name="option" class="option" id="0">
            <option value="0">ZERO</option>
            <option value="1">ONE</option>
            <option value="2">TWO</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    </td><td>
    </td><td>
    </td><td>
</tr>

<tr class='child1'>
    <td colspan="2"><img class="parent" src="show.gif">
        <select name="option" class="option" id="1">
            <option value="0">ZERO</option>
            <option value="1">ONE</option>
            <option value="2">TWO</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    </td><td>
    </td><td>
    </td><td>
</tr>
```

I'm using JQuery to try and find the id of the Select and the Selected Value for each class `.child + id`.

```
$('.child' + id).each(function(i, obj) {
  // How do I get the Select ID and Selected Value ?
});
```

I'm not sure how to get the Select ID and Selected Value for each entry that matches `class1`

Can someone advise how to do this ?

Thanks

UPDATE.
adding console.log(this) shows the correct row, I've tried:
    `test = $(this).next("select").val();` but that returns undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things: I fixed your unmatched td's, I added a button to demonstrate that the code works properly, and I removed the unique child class as it seems a bit erroneous (you can add it back in if you want, and it grabs the selected id and the value.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  
  $('.child').each(function(i, obj) {
    console.log("Index: " + i)
    value = $(this).find(".option").val()
    selectedId = $(this).find(".option").attr("id")
    console.log("Has the value " + value + " and the selectedId of " + selectedId);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class='child'>
    <td colspan="2"><img class="parent" src="show.gif">
        <select name="option" class="option" id="0">
            <option value="0">ZERO</option>
            <option value="1">ONE</option>
            <option value="2">TWO</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>
    </td><td>
    </td><td>
    </td><td>
</tr>

<tr class='child'>
    <td colspan="2"><img class="parent" src="show.gif">
        <select name="option" class="option" id="1">
            <option value="0">ZERO</option>
            <option value="1">ONE</option>
            <option value="2">TWO</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>
    </td><td>
    </td><td>
    </td><td>
</tr>
</table>
<button>Test results</button>
```

Comment: The `td`s was a copy & paste typo. The real code is the correct way around.

Comment: You're welcome, if you could mark as solution, it'd help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.child' + id).each(function(i, obj) {
  var selectID = $(this).find("select").attr("id");
  var selectValue = $(this).find("select").val();
});
```

only if you have on select inside your childN

Comment: Your HTML is wrong, you close and open td instead of open and close td

Comment: sorry that was a copy & paste typo. The real code is the correct way around.